# Upload image ref url save in firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/upload-image-ref-firestore?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

I'm using AngularFire2 to upload images, I wonder how I can save that reference of the Firebase Storage image in a firestore document.

[image]

I'm trying but all I get is an empty field:

[image]

Any idea?

component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  tests: Observable<any[]>;
 
  uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
  downloadURL: Observable<string>;

  forma: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('f') form;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private fs: FirebaseService, private storage: AngularFireStorage ) { 
    this.forma = fb.group ({
      imagenDestacada: [ '', Validators.required],

    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tests = this.fs.getTests();
  }

  uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = `proyectos4/name1`;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

    // observe percentage changes
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    // get notified when the download URL is available
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
        this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL()
        this.fs.addTest(this.forma.value)
        console.log( this.downloadURL ) 
      })    
    )
    .subscribe()

  }


}
```

html

```html
<h2>Test upload ref save in firestore</h2>

<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="crearTest()" novalidate>
  <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>{{ uploadPercent | async }}</div>
  <br>
  <a [href]="downloadURL | async">{{ downloadURL | async }}</a>
  <br>
  <input type="text" formControlName="imagenDestacada" [value]="downloadURL | async" placeholder="url Image">
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- <button type="submit" [disabled]="!forma.valid">Crear Test</button> -->
</form>

<hr>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let test of tests | async">Imagen: {{test.imagenDestacada}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant code inside the question instead of linking to some other place to view it.

Comment: Okay, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`fileRef.getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL) doesn't return a download URL directly. Instead it returns a promise, that resolves when the download URL is available. This means that you need to wait for the promise to resolve before logging the download URL or writing it to the database:

```
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    fileRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      this.downloadURL = url;
      this.fs.addTest(this.forma.value)
      console.log( this.downloadURL ) 
    });
  })    
)
```

Comment: I assume that after `(url)` this is missing `=>` ?. Still it marks me error in `then` says `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable <any>'` Any idea?

Comment: Good catch on the missing `=>`. Added. From the error message it sounds like your `fileRef` is an AngularFire2 ref (instead of a regular JavaScript `Storage.Reference`). I'm actually not sure how those work/don't work.

Comment: instead of `then` you  have to use `subscribe` because of the usage of an observable